# Neo4j: How time-consuming is EVERY branch between node A and F?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

The following graph is given:

```
    -> B --> E -
   /            \ 
A -              -> F
   \            /
    -> C --> D -
```

All nodes are of type task. As properties, they have a start time and an end time (both are of the data type DateTime).
All relationships are CONNECT_TO and are directed to the right. The relationships have no properties.

Can somebody help me how the following query should look like in Cypher:
How time-consuming is EVERY branch between node A and F?

A list as result would be fine:

```
Path           Duration [minutes]
---------------------------------
A->B->E->F     100
A->C->D->F      50
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am delighted to hear that the proposed answer works perfectly for you. Happy to help - and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider accepting answers, if you believe the proposed solution was helpful to your problem. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to green filled in. This helps the community keeping the focus on older, not answered questions.

Answer (score 1):

### Creating your graph

The first statement creates the nodes, the second the relationships between them.

```
CREATE
  (TaskA:Task {name: 'TaskA', time:10}),
  (TaskB:Task {name: 'TaskB', time:20}),
  (TaskC:Task {name: 'TaskC', time:30}),
  (TaskD:Task {name: 'TaskD', time:10}),
  (TaskE:Task {name: 'TaskE', time:40}),
  (TaskF:Task {name: 'TaskF', time:10})

CREATE
  (TaskA)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(TaskB),
  (TaskB)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(TaskE),
  (TaskE)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(TaskF),
  (TaskA)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(TaskC),
  (TaskC)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(TaskD),
  (TaskD)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(TaskF);
```

### Your desired solution

1. Defining your start node (Task A)
2. Finding path of variable length
3. Defining your end node (Task F)
4. Retrieve all task nodes for each path
5. Sum the duration for all tasks of each path
6. Bonus: amount of tasks per path

**Neo4j Statement:**

```
//           |----------- 1 -----------|  |----- 2 ----|  |----------- 3 -----------|
MATCH path = (taskA:Task {name: 'TaskA'})-[:CONNECT_TO*]->(taskF:Task {name: 'TaskF'})
UNWIND
// |-- 4 -|
nodes(path) AS task
//           |---- 5 -----|                  |--- 6 ----|
RETURN path, sum(task.time) AS timeConsumed, length(path)+1 AS taskAmount;
```

### Result

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤════════════════╤════════════╕
│"path"                                                                │ "timeConsumed" │"taskAmount"│
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════╡
│[{"name":"TaskA","time":10},{},{"name":"TaskB","time":20},{"name":"Tas│80              │4           │
│kB","time":20},{},{"name":"TaskE","time":40},{"name":"TaskE","time":40│                │            │
│},{},{"name":"TaskF","time":10}]                                      │                │            │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────┤
│[{"name":"TaskA","time":10},{},{"name":"TaskC","time":30},{"name":"Tas│60              │4           │
│kC","time":30},{},{"name":"TaskD","time":10},{"name":"TaskD","time":10│                │            │
│},{},{"name":"TaskF","time":10}]                                      │                │            │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Works perfect for me. Thanks.
Additional question: Is it possible to format the path-column? At the moment all properties are shown, but it would be enough if only the property "name" for every node in the path would be shown.

Comment: I found a solution: 
RETURN reduce(s=head(nodes(path)).name, n in tail(nodes(path)) | s+" -> "+n.name) AS NodesInBranch, ...

Comment: @Riegel You can also use reduce to get the sum without needing to unwind the path first.